# How do I rename my SVN sandbox?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, sandbox

I've checked out a local sandbox and to c:\Sandbox\old

Can I rename that exact sandbox to c:\Sandbox\new without any consequences?

I've researched and it looks like maybe an SVN switch or relocate might do it?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to rename the folder on your local computer, not the SVN repo, then yes you can just rename the folder and be fine. All of the svn metadata is stored inside a `.svn` directory inside that folder.

Comment: This is correct. Please take extra attention not to rename folders _inside_ your working copy.

Answer (score 0):

switch or relocate needed on changing from server-side (relocation of repository to new URL)

WC is fully portable and can be moved to new drives|renamed in-place